# How to color HTML table cells according to their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table that is populated with some JSON data via JavaScript.

- My table has both negative and positive values. I am trying to color these cells
- Like: if value is in between -100 to -1000 i want to color them with pink
- Like: if value is above -1000 eg: -1500,-1200 I want to color them with red
- similarly if values are positive, like +20,50,200, I want to color the cells green
- And if value is 0 then any other color

I know i can do it with DOM manipulation in JavaScript but I am not understanding the logic to check the values.

**my code snippet**

```js
var data = [

  {
    "itemcode": "1125",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -35
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1126",
    "itemname": "Khara Sev-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1127",
    "itemname": "Butter Muruku-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -47
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1128",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -12
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1129",
    "itemname": "Ambode-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1130",
    "itemname": "Chow Chow-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 69
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1131",
    "itemname": "Potato Chips",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 24
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1132",
    "itemname": "Tangy Groundnut-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 216
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1133",
    "itemname": "Rice Kodubale-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 105
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1134",
    "itemname": "Puva Chivda-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 44
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1135",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -40
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1136",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -340
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1137",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 40
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1138",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 80
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1139",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -1240
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1140",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Triffle Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -2125
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1141",
    "itemname": "Liche Chocolate Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 20
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1142",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 1450
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1143",
    "itemname": "Mixed Fruit Chocolate Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 130
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1144",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 835
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1145",
    "itemname": "Pineapple Cake",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1146",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Cake",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 26
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1147",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 90
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1148",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 500gm",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 1070
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1149",
    "itemname": "Cherry White Forest",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 20
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1150",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Almond Gautex",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 69
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1151",
    "itemname": "Death By Chocolate",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 24
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1152",
    "itemname": "Blue Berry",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 216
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1153",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Ice-Cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 105
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1154",
    "itemname": "French Vanilla Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1155",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 112
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1156",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1157",
    "itemname": "Pista Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -230
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1158",
    "itemname": "Black Currant Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -120
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1159",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -6700
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1160",
    "itemname": "Tiramisu Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -90
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1161",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -1060
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1162",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 10
  },

  {
    "itemcode": "1285",
    "itemname": "Set Menu",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let itemCode = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (itemCode.indexOf(element.itemcode) == -1) {
      itemCode.push(element.itemcode);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    itemCode: itemCode,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  itemCode = data.itemCode;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("BillCountTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Item Code"; // header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Item Name"; //header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element; //populating outlet
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.difference); //calculating total outlet wise
      }
    });

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-in'); //populating outlet wise total
    th.classList.add("text-right");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-Center");

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  itemCode.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element; //populating item code
    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.itemcode == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.difference);
          el = d.difference;
          In = d.itemname;
        }
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

    });

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = In; //populating item name
    td.classList.add("text-left");

    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="BillCountTable"></table>
</div>
```

As my code is little bit lengthy because of JSON data.. i have commented the lines in my code for knowing all of you, what i am doing where

Comment: If you're using jQuery then why are you not using it?

Comment: The formulation of your question is not clear: You mean each row has among other 2 columns 'JAYANAGAR' and 'Mallesharam', one of the is egal to 0 and the other has a value different from 0, and may be positive or negative. You want to set the color of the entire row according to the values of the 2 columns by consedering for each row the column with the value not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like this inside your loop of the item codes:

```
if(element < -1000) td.style="background:red";
else if(element >= -1000 && element <= -100) td.style="background: pink";
else if(element == 0) td.style="background: ANY OTHER COLOR";
else if(element > 0) td.style="background: green";
```

Alternatively you can add classes with the specific color instead of using the `style tag`

Edit:
If you want it for the whole row, just give the style/class to the row element like this:

```
let row = document.createElement("tr");
if(element < -1000) row.style="background:red";
else if(element >= -1000 && element <= -100) row.style="background: pink";
else if(element == 0) row.style="background: ANY OTHER COLOR";
else if(element > 0) row.style="background: green";
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w15psebd/

Comment: sir i only want to color cell not the full row..as i am replacing row with td but its colouring other cells

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes to add a different style to each cell and a function to determine the class to add to the cell from its value. This will allows you to keep the styling specified in your CSS:

```
function getColorClass(val) {
  const value = parseFloat(val);
  if (value < -1000) {
    return 'color1';
  } else if (value >= -1000 && value < -100) {
    return 'color2';
  } else if (value > 0) {
    return 'color3';
  } else if (value === 0) {
    return 'color4';
  }
}
```

When creating the `td`, you use it like this:

```
td.classList.add(getColorClass(el));
```

```js
var data = [

  {
    "itemcode": "1125",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -35
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1126",
    "itemname": "Khara Sev-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1127",
    "itemname": "Butter Muruku-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -47
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1128",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -12
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1129",
    "itemname": "Ambode-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1130",
    "itemname": "Chow Chow-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 69
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1131",
    "itemname": "Potato Chips",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 24
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1132",
    "itemname": "Tangy Groundnut-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 216
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1133",
    "itemname": "Rice Kodubale-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 105
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1134",
    "itemname": "Puva Chivda-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 44
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1135",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -40
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1136",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -340
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1137",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 40
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1138",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 80
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1139",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -1240
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1140",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Triffle Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": -2125
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1141",
    "itemname": "Liche Chocolate Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 20
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1142",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 1450
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1143",
    "itemname": "Mixed Fruit Chocolate Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 130
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1144",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "difference": 835
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1145",
    "itemname": "Pineapple Cake",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1146",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Cake",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 26
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1147",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 90
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1148",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 500gm",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 1070
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1149",
    "itemname": "Cherry White Forest",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 20
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1150",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Almond Gautex",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 69
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1151",
    "itemname": "Death By Chocolate",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 24
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1152",
    "itemname": "Blue Berry",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 216
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1153",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Ice-Cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 105
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1154",
    "itemname": "French Vanilla Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1155",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 112
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1156",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1157",
    "itemname": "Pista Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -230
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1158",
    "itemname": "Black Currant Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -120
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1159",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -6700
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1160",
    "itemname": "Tiramisu Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -90
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1161",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": -1060
  },
  {
    "itemcode": "1162",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 10
  },

  {
    "itemcode": "1285",
    "itemname": "Set Menu",
    "outlet": "Mallesharam",
    "difference": 0
  }
]
function getColorClass(val) {
  const value = parseFloat(val);
  if (value < -1000) {
    return 'color1';
  } else if (value >= -1000 && value < -100) {
    return 'color2';
  } else if (value > 0) {
    return 'color3';
  } else if (value === 0) {
    return 'color4';
  }
}

let formatData = function(data) {
  let itemCode = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (itemCode.indexOf(element.itemcode) == -1) {
      itemCode.push(element.itemcode);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    itemCode: itemCode,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  itemCode = data.itemCode;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("BillCountTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Item Code"; // header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Item Name"; //header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element; //populating outlet
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.difference); //calculating total outlet wise
      }
    });

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-in'); //populating outlet wise total
    th.classList.add("text-right");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-Center");

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  itemCode.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element; //populating item code
    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.itemcode == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.difference);
          el = d.difference;
          In = d.itemname;
        }
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add(getColorClass(el));
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

    });

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = In; //populating item name
    td.classList.add("text-left");

    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
.color1 {
  background-color: #f55;
}
.color2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
.color3 {
  background-color: #0a0;
}
.color4 {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="BillCountTable"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css based on the condition as per your requirement in 'itemCode' foreach loop. Make sure you applied logic on 'el' not on element to apply css only on td's.

```
itemCode.forEach(element => {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = element; //populating item code
        row.appendChild(td);
        let total = 0;
        outlets.forEach(outlet => {
          let el = 0;
          data.forEach(d => {
            if (d.itemcode == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
              total += parseInt(d.difference);
              el = d.difference;
              In = d.itemname;
            }
          });
          console.log(el);
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString("en-in");
          td.classList.add("text-right");

          var tdVal = el;
          if (tdVal <= -1000) {
            td.style="background: pink";
          } else if (tdVal > -1000 && tdVal< -100) {
            td.style="background: red";
          } else if (tdVal > 0) {
            td.style="background: green";
          } else if (tdVal === 0) {
            td.style="background: grey";
          }
      row.appendChild(td);
    });

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = In; //populating item name
    td.classList.add("text-left");

    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
```

Hope this helps.